# extended real number

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question about this,

so I know that the extended complex plane $ \mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ is the set of all complex number $\mathbb{C} $ plus a point of infinity $\infty$.  There is only one infinity in this set since it doesn't make sense to talk about a complex number being negative or positive but it makes sense to talk about its norm being large or small.

but what about the set $ \mathbb{R}_{\infty}$? 
is this set just the set of $ \mathbb{R}$ plus a point of infinity $ \infty$. but how come there is only one infinity in this sense while in this set it makes sense to talk about a number being negative or positive, should there be another negative infinity??

thank you.

Comment: You can do it in either of two ways.  Either add one point and create an infinitely large "circle" out of the real numbers plus this point.  That point is denoted $\infty$.  This is called the [Alexandroff compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of the reals.  Or add two new points, one denoted $+\infty$ such that $+\infty \gt a$ for all real $a$ and the other denoted $-\infty$ such that $-\infty \lt a$ for all real $a$.  This is called the [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got it

Comment: The first compactification in @Bye_World's comment is a closer analogue to the extended complex plane in that both are projective lines $\Bbb P(\Bbb F^2)$.